# Cannot find a particular Google I/O video

Tags: java, googleio

I remember watching a Google I/O video on YT (I think so).
Probably there were two lecturers (not very young), and one was involved in writing java utils collections. One guy from audience thanked for writing some of java util's code.There was some shoots of the audience (One of the lecturers sat among it), that is a little bit unusual for G I/O videos. But I am not sure of any of this.

**Lecturer also said that most of the programmer work is solving problems** (something, like that. I want to cite that part).

Do you remember the title of this video?

EDIT: It was not in this video (I only remember that audience were mostly young folks, and lecturer was a nice older guy ). If someone will find any video or other material which contains statements similar to bold ones i will be gratefuller.

Comment: It sounds like one of them was Josh Bloch, but beyond that there's much too little detail to identify a specific video.

Comment: if that was the video you were looking for, what about accepting the answer :3

Comment: It was not, I have mixed it all up (I have wathed it, and nobody talks about what is to be programmer or something), but sure, why not :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the video you're looking for:

GTUG - Using the Google Collections Library for Java (1 of 2)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM&feature=relmfu

A talk by Kevin Bourrillion, introduced by Josh Bloch, the guy who wrote the utils and the author of Effective Java. He is the guy sitting with the audience.

Answer (score 0):

A "GTUG - Using the Google Collections Library for Java" playlist (2 videos)

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgXQ9P4JMIWkQbjz7NHVWxn6YsargHtoY

Year 2018

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.